# ByteCountFormatter number formate

Tags: ios, swift, byte, formatter

I'm using ByteCountFormatter for converting Byte to Appropriate String,

```
func sizeFormate(size: Int) -> String {
    let bcf = ByteCountFormatter()
    bcf.allowedUnits = [.useMB,.useGB]
    bcf.countStyle = .binary
    return bcf.string(fromByteCount: Int64(size))
}
```

for example:

```
sizeFormate(size: 763917940) // output: 728.5 MB

// what I need is 728 MB // digit should not have fraction part
```

How can we achieve this formate?

Answer (score 0):

ByteCountFormatter have one property named: [isAdaptive](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bytecountformatter/1417887-isadaptive) and by Default it is true. To hide fraction part just make this false

Updated code:

```
func sizeFormate(size: Int) -> String {
    let bcf = ByteCountFormatter()
    bcf.allowedUnits = [.useMB,.useGB]
    bcf.countStyle = .binary
    bcf.isAdaptive = false // change
    return bcf.string(fromByteCount: Int64(size))
}
```

Note: keep that in mind that it round of from 0.5 to 1

it still shows fraction digits..
any other way?